# SELECT blocks UPDATE in Snapshot Isolation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction, snapshot-isolation, tempdb-version-store

We have a database running on SQL Server 2016 SP1 Enterprise and on which `Allow Snapshot Isolation` is enabled. In this scenario readers do not block writers and writers do not block readers.

Today we saw that a `SELECT`-query was blocking an `UPDATE`-query.
These are the queries at issue:

First query:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
SELECT TOP 10 Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM [dbo].[TABLE1] 
WHERE ([Field1] = @SV1 AND (1=1))
ORDER BY A.[Field1] ASC,A.[Field2] ASC
OPTION (KEEP PLAN, KEEPFIXED PLAN, LOOP JOIN)
```

Second query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table1] SET [Field4]= @V128, [Field5]= @V140, [Field6]= @V141 WHERE [Field3] = @ID0
```

If a understand versioning correctly, a `SELECT`-query do not use any locks because it works on a snapshot of the data (taken at the start of the transaction). How is it possible that the `SELECT`-query blocks the `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if @@trancount <> 0 then that SELECT will run with the current transaction isolation level.  Which (unless it already happens to be SNAPSHOT) will require S locks for reading data.

If you want all SELECTS using the default READ COMMITTED isolation level to use row versioning instead of S locks, set READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT on the database.